# Changing VBA code to affect workbook instead of sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have found this code on how to change chart design in a whole sheet, and i would like to change it to affect the whole workbook instead of just my active sheet.

```
Sub ChangeCharts()
    Dim myChart As ChartObject
    For Each myChart In ActiveSheet.ChartObjects
        myChart.Chart.ApplyChartTemplate ( _
"C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates\Charts\exemple.crtx")
    Next myChart
End Sub
```

This is the code. I would appreciate it if someone could help me with this change, I tried myself but I couldn't make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to change it to affect the whole workbook

Iterate the workbook sheets, iterating all worksheet charts.

```
Sub ChangeChartsInWorkbook()
    Dim OneSheet As WorkSheet
    Dim OneChart As ChartObject
    For Each OneSheet In ThisWorkbook.Sheets ' or in a certain book
        For Each OneChart In OneSheet.ChartObjects
            OneChart.Chart.ApplyChartTemplate ("C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates\Charts\exemple.crtx")
        Next OneChart 
    Next OneSheet
End Sub
```